# Upload data on a button click event

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

I am new to programming. I want to be able to upload files on a website that save into my database when I upload  the file and the send an email of the files that I uploaded to two other parties 
how can I achieve this goal?

This is the code that I currently have but I get errors of file name does not exist in current context?

```
protected void Upload(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
    string contentType = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType;
    using (Stream fs = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream)
    {
        using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
        {
            byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                string query = "insert into tblFiles values (@Name, @ContentType, @Data)";
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@File Name", filename);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContentType", contentType);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data", bytes);
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
}

protected void Upload_Bt1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MailMessage mailObj = new MailMessage(
    txtFrom.Text, txtTo.Text, txtSubject.Text, txtBody.Text);
    SmtpClient SMTPServer = new SmtpClient("127.0.0.1");
    try
    {
        SMTPServer.Send(mailObj);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Label1.Text = ex.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should look aat the `FileUpload` control http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Please post the exact error message and stacktrace

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience but I got the problem sorted